# Control workspace location at startup

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, workspace

I searched all day long yesterday but i didn't found an answer to my problem.
I would like to hook the workspace selection process of eclipse in order to forbid spaces in the path of the workspace location (typed in the workspace dialog selection launched at startup).
Do someone know how i can achieve this ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The workspace selection is done in `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication` which is the main `IApplication` class for Eclipse. This does not have any way to change the workspace validation.

The only way to change this would be to define a new `IApplication` class and build a custom RCP version of Eclipse based on that. I don't think this is possible without accessing some internal Eclipse classes so would violate the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)